# Installing .tar.gz package as easily as .deb package

Tags: software-installation, software-center, deb, tar

I wanted to download and install the latest version of Webstorm this morning.

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=linux

Jetbrains does not offer a .deb install for Webstorm, only a .tar.gz.

It turns out, it's much easier to install a .deb file on Ubuntu. Why can't the Ubuntu Software Center install a .tar/.tar.gz package automatically, the way it can install a .deb package?

Comment: Unlike .deb, tar packages aren't conventional. There is no way to know what's in there, and how they should be installed.

Comment: right, so why not make some standard...like tar.std or whatever

Comment: My main question is why Jetbrains/Webstorm does not offer a .deb download - and why they only offer a .tar.gz download. Seems like it should not be that hard for them to provide a .deb download instead. But idk.

Comment: All those whys are good questions that go beyond the scope of this site. You should contact "them" directly, and ask.

Comment: yeah I did do that, don't have answer yet

Comment: This is why you can't just make some standard: https://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. A `.tar.gz` package is a compressed tarball that contains the files of the program. Generally either in the online documentation, or in the tarball, there are instructions. Package managers cannot process these due to the inconsistency in how they're packaged. The reason some software developers don't give `.deb` files is because they only work with `dpkg` (found on Debian-like systems), and thus they would also need to make packages for all other major package managers, thus massively increasing the time spent each time they push a new release.